# Flash error: Warning: Filter will not render. Doesnt display some fonts

Tags: flash, fonts, typography

I open a project that i have in flash today and it suddenly give me the error:

> Warning: Filter will not render.  The DisplayObject's filtered
>   dimensions (26843549, 20132662) are too large to be drawn.

And i notice that the font that i was using in my flahs project is not displaying. It is in the library but i cant see it when compiling and Flash gives me the error that i posted above. Also when im working inside flash, without compiling the type also dosnt display. The textfield is there, the text is written, is also static; but it dosnt display anything. The rare thing is that the font works fine in ilustrator and in other programs. And its not only in this project, in previous versions that used to work fine i checked and there is also the same problem now. Please help, its getting me crazy, i didnt found anything similar in the internet either here. The font im using is called Cyclone but is not the only one that suddenly has this problem in flash. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having this problem for the first time today as well - can't find anything online, and no idea what to even try!  If I switch to "Arial" or a few other fonts, it works, but any "Good" (non-system fonts likely) fonts just show as invisible!  Help!

Comment: If I highlight the invisible text-field, and select anything other than "Anti-alias for readability", the font shows up and looks good, but then when I click out of the box, it disappears again.

Comment: And if I select the font, but choose "Bitmap text [no anti-alias]", then it shows up fine (though it looks terrible).  So - it has to be something to do with the aliasing (I assume).

Comment: Update: on all the fonts where it seems to be a problem, their alternate styles (bold, super bold...etc etc) don't show up in the dropdown - the dropdown is actually grayed out.

Comment: When viewing the "Fonts" directory, if "Font embeddability" is set to "Print and preview", then this error occurs. Not yet sure if there's a way around it or why it just started happening.

Comment: It appears using "TLF Text" instead of "Classic Text" makes it work, but that forces you to use AS3 - which I'd rather not have to change all my code just to use a font that was working just fine a few days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a recent Windows update. After experiencing the same problem I found the following thread on Adobe Flash Pro forums:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/4920976#4920976

Basically, we have to either roll back one of the updates (I believe it's KB2753842), or wait for Microsoft to fix the issue. In the meantime, you could use some "simple" fonts such as Arial.

Comment: You're very welcome! Thanks for the points. BTW, a few months ago I had to roll back a system update and that messed up my .as files! It seems that Microsoft treats .as source files as system files. Not sure if this has been fixed, but here's one more reason to back up often :)